# UseEffect Filtering and Sorting combined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, supabase

Currently, I use two `useEffect` instances, one for sorting data and another for filtering data. I want to modify the supabase query run in each useEffect so that the reply from supabase depends on the filter or sorting option chosen on the page. Also, I have a column that identifies data values, I want to map all the distinct values from the table and list them on the page as a filter.

These are the `useEffect()` instances in my app. Should I be calling the database multiple times here? Once the DB is loaded with data, load times may slow down if I write a common query and parse the data locally.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchSmoothies = async () => {
    let filterQuery = supabase
      .from('main')
      .select('*')
      .eq('color', filterBy)
    ...
  })
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchSmoothies = async () => {
    const { data, error } = await supabase
      .from('main')
      .select('*')
      .order(orderBy, { ascending: false })
    ...
  })
```

I am calling the filter buttons manually. Let's say supabase has a column with the following distinct values - Blue, Green, Red, and Yellow.  I want to map the buttons dynamically using `main.map(()=> ..)` but not sure how to do that or if there is a batter way to do this.

```html
<div className='order-by'>
  <p>Filter By:</p>
  <p>
    <button onClick={() => setFilterBy('Sam Malone')}>Sam Malone</button>
    <button onClick={() => setFilterBy('Glen')}>Glen</button>
    {filterBy}
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Those effetcs will run _every_ time your component is (re-)rendered. I'd expect them to have `filterBy` and `orderBy` respectively as their dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

> These are the useEffect() instances in my app. Should I be calling the database multiple times here? Once the DB is loaded with data, load times may slow down if I write a common query and parse the data locally.

Efficiency-wise, these 2 operations (equality check, and order result) should be together, but you should also give your variable `orderBy` a default value so the syntax will always be valid, so the `fetchSmoothies` should become

```
  const fetchSmoothies = async () => {
    let filterQuery = supabase
      .from('main')
      .select('*')
      .eq('color', filterBy)
      .order((orderBy || 'id'), { ascending: false }) // fallback to be ordered by 'id'
  })
```

But if it doesn't bottleneck the performance of you app, it's probably okay to keep it simple and stupid (KISS principle) until the improvement is needed.

> I am calling the filter buttons manually. Let's say supabase has a column with the following distinct values - Blue, Green, Red, and Yellow. I want to map the buttons dynamically using main.map(()=> ..) but not sure how to do that or if there is a batter way to do this.

Assuming the variable `main` holds all the names you need (Red, Green, Blue, and Yello), then you can do the following --

```
      <div className="order-by">
        <p>Filter By:</p>
        <p>
          {main.map((name: string) => {
            return (
              <button key={name} onClick={() => setFilterBy(name)}>
                Sam Malone
              </button>
            )
          })}
        </p>
      </div>
```